# Shifting array to left or right OCaml

Tags: arrays, ocaml

I'm having some trouble around arrays in OCaml.
Namely, I want to just shift the elements to the right or left based on a value I pass.
Example: `# let a = [|1;2;3;4;5|], # shift_array a 7;;- : int array array = [|4;5;1;2;3|]`

I wrote the following code but I keep getting a syntax error where the second array is formed.

```
let shift_array arr x =
  let size = Array.length arr in
  let sec_arr = Array.make size 0 in
  for i = 0 to size - 1 do
    if i < x
    then (sec_arr.(size - x + 1) <- arr.(i))
    else (sec_arr.(i-x) <- arr.(i))
  done;;
```

I'm just not 100% sure how to print out the new array.

EDIT: fixed it by adding `in` to the second and third line.

The problem now is that the function has type `int array -> int -> unit` and the one I'm trying to get is `'a array -> int -> 'a array`. Is there some way to work around that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `let size = Array.length arr in`, notice the `in`, which you're missing.

The `let` expression in OCaml has the form `let <var> = <expr> in <body>` and should not be (but commonly is) confused with the let *definition* that can occur only on the top-level (as an element of a module), which has form `let <name> = <body>`.

In your example, you have both, the top-level definition, `let shift_array = <body>` and two let expressions (though, you have used the wrong syntax for them.

EDIT:

Since OP edited the post, here is the corresponding edit.

You function doesn't return anything, it creates a new array, does the cycle, but doesn't return anything but the `unit` value (which is the value to which the for cycle evaluates). So you have to add one more line, that will contain the expression, to which the whole function will evaluate. Hint the sequencing operator `;` is what you need, when you have expression `x;y;z` the computer evaluates `x`, then `y`, and finally `z` and the value of the whole expression of `x;y;z` is the value of `z`.

Comment: I've put the in's where they belong, I've edited the post with the new problem.

Comment: that's cheating, you're posting two different questions in one. Questions in SO should be like lists in OCaml - immutable :D Anyway, I will answer, but in general, it is better to post one question per problem. You can also use Discord or Discuss to get more interactive help on OCaml.